# Signed binary multiplication and signed binary division

Tags: verilog, unsigned, signed

What is the difference between the result of the multiplication when multiplying two unsigned numbers vs multiplying two signed numbers?

What is the difference between the remainder and quotient when dividing two signed numbers vs dividing two unsigned numbers?

Answer (score 0):

An example may be illuminating.

```
module top;

reg [3:0] a;
reg [3:0] b;

reg [7:0] r1;
reg [7:0] r2;

initial begin
   a = 4'hc;
   b = 4'h5;
   r1 = a * b;  // 12 * 5
   r2 = $signed(a) * $signed(b); //-4 * 5
   $display("r1 = %b", r1);
   $display("r2 = %b", r2);
end


endmodule
```

Result:

```
r1 = 00111100 (60)
r2 = 11101100 (-20)
```

The difference is that signed numbers utilize the MSB of the vector as an indicator of sign (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), no really, read this) that shifts the range of expressible numbers from `[0..2^n-1]` to `[-2^(n-1)..2^(n-1)-1]`

A couple of things to note:

1. Verilog is odd and will only produce a signed results if *both*
   operands are signed.
2. You can mark a reg/wire as signed like `reg signed [3:0] foo` or with the `$signed` system task.  The latter is often useful if you have sub-expressions you want to treat as signed.  For example, taking a bit slice of a vector is always unsigned even if the original var is signed.
3. The link I provided also covers the slight changes in mechanics required to get the right answer when multiplying signed quantities.

For purposes of Verilog's behavior division is essentially the same although unless dealing with strict powers of 2 is not usually synthesisable.

Answer (score 0):

just a bit different view based on Brian's example

Signed vs unsigned arithmetic in verilog causes differences in sign propagation and relational operations. Regular arithmetic on 2-complement data produces the same results for signed and unsigned if no sign extension is involved

so in this case, if r1 and r2 would be of size '4' (as the operands) you would get the same results:

```
r1 = 1100 was (60) 
r2 = 1100 was (-20)
```

In Brian's case the size of the result of the expression is 8; Verilog will extend your operands to occupy the 8-bit space. In case of the signed 'a' it will sing extend it and this will make the difference:

```
unsigned a[3:0] <1100> --> tmp[7:0] --> 00001100
signed a[3:0] <1100> --> tmp[7:0] --> 11111100
```

So, if a[3] is '1', it is considered a sign and gets sign promoted to the left. now, your arithmetic looks like the following:

```
unsigned: tmpa(00001100) * tmpb(00000101) --> 00111100
signed:   tmpa(11111100) * tmpb(00000101) --> 11101100
```

When you display the second result as an integer, it will yet be sign extended to 32 bits and will be displayed as (-20)